# why do i get wrong base 64 string in the code below?

Tags: android

I have the code below to decode a bitmap to a base64 string.

```
for(String e:paths)
              {
                  String usepath=e.replace("%", "//");
                  Bitmap m=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(usepath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                    m.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); 
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  
                    String bb= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    Log.e("Photo", bb);
```

String usepath prints like

```
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140424_132023.jpg
```

I have saved the image on my pc and used an online tool to decode it to base64 and i got a long string of around 650kb(after uploading to google app engine) yet the string i get using the above code is like 10% of that and does not display the image .

But i can use the same image path to set an image view and it works like below

```
 Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(usepath);
          holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Any reasons why the base64 encoding failing?

Ronald

Comment: You are doing nothing with String bb. At least you did not post code for it. What is its length exactly? What is the filelength of your image exactly? What do you mean with "does not display the image"? Where did you try to display it? Sorry you speak about encode and decode but mix them up.

Comment: If you want to encode a file to base64 then do not use Bitmap and BitmapFactory and certainly not Bitmap:compress() because you will end up with different bytes. Just open the file and read in in a byte array which you encode.

Comment: Hi. What i have is an image path. I want to use the image path to encode the image to base64. Any code suggestion?

Comment: Forgot to ask the size of byte[] b. You forgot to answer my questions. I knew already that you had an image path. I knew already that you wanted to encode an image.

Comment: b is the bytearray of the image bitmap which i encode  to base64 string. I believe the problem is that i compress the image thus getting low bytes. I am trying to write code to use the actual image .

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the flag **Base64.URL_SAFE** to the encoding method.

Consider also that if the image is too large you may not get all the bytes you need in the String (you may try writing to a temp file previous to send the content).

Comment: So it may not serve my purpose? because i want to encode the image into base64 and upload to google app engine .